# Is there a way to compile webdriverio tests to standard selenium files

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I have a large number of automated tests written using webdriverio.
I am trying to integrate a security scanner into my build pipeline that is able to use a selenium file to automate the steps needed to get my SPA into a state that security checks can be run.  Is there a way to re-use work I have done in webdriverio (pageobjects and such) and convert to a standard selenium file?

Comment: What do you mean by a "standard selenium file"?

Comment: What security scanner is that? If it can run Selenium scripts it should be able to run WebdriverIO too. Also can you just run your functional WebdriverIO tests and have a separate test with Selenium for security checks?